# Modifying contact information

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I'm trying to insert and update a piece of information on an **existing** contact so I've created a sample application in order to develop the functionality. All I want my sample app to do is to insert (or if present) update an email address on a contact.

I'm selecting a contact through the system Intent like so:

```
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI), PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

The URI which is returned is that of the `Contact` (`RawContact`?) which was selected and comes in this form:
`content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r2-2A90214945/2`.

I can pull back all of the `Data` (`RawContact`?) items on this by performing the following code:

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(mContactUri, null, null, null, null);
try {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        for(int i=0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            String message = cursor.getColumnName(i);
            Log.v("", message);
        }
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

From this I should be able to determine if the contact already has an [CommonDataTypes.Email](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.html) `Data` member:

```
cursor.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE) != -1;
```

And then perform one of the following to either `Insert` or `Update` the [Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html):

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(mContactUri)
    .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(Email.DISPLAY_NAME, "somebody@android.com")
    .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_HOME)
    .build());
getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

But this gives me an exception:
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: URI: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r2-2A90314945/2, calling user:`

Hopefully someone can see what I've missed.

PS, I'm using these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: ok , i will remove it. thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The Android people need to update their [documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html). It actually served to make me know *less* about what was happening than I would have gotten from guessing. It suggests that you can pull back a `Contact`, which will contain many `RawContacts` which will contain `Data`.

That interpretation is completely wrong. ContactContracts data is instead three normal average everyday database tables*:

**ContactContract Tables**

**Table: [Contacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html)**

> Access URI: `Contacts.CONTENT_URI`
>
> Primary Key**: `Data._ID`
>
> Description:
>
> This table contains information about a Contact (when was it added, what's is it's user icon, does it have a custom ringtone).
>
> Relationship: It has a 1-to-many relationship with the `RawContact` table.

**Table: [RawContacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html)**

> Access URI: `RawContacts.CONTENT_URI`
>
> Primary Key: `Data._ID`
>
> Foreign Key**: `Data.CONTACT_ID`
>
> Description:
>
> This table contains information about a related set of Data items. A RawContact could contain Email Type, Email Display Name, Phone Number, Phone Display Name, etc. A RawContact can be aggregated with other RawContacts to make a `Contact` as a user sees it. A Contact could contain just one RawContact.
>
> Relationship: It has a 1-to-many relationship with the `Data` table.

**Table: [Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html)**

> Access URI: `Data.CONTENT_URI`
>
> Primary Key: `Data._ID`
>
> Foreign Key: `Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID`
>
> Description:
>
> This table contains a single field of information. An email address, A phone number, A phone number type (home/work), A nickname, A display name.

**In answer to the question**

I've uploaded the entire sample project to GitHub in order to allow others to see how to query, update and insert records using ContactContract.

You can find the project to download here:
https://github.com/gwoodhouse/ContactContractSample

If you just want to look at the java code performing the query/update/insert here is the class file:
https://github.com/gwoodhouse/ContactContractSample/blob/master/ContactsIntegration/src/com/woodhouse/example/activity/ContactsIntegrationActivity.java

Hope this helps!

<sub>*Not a table, but a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html)</sub>

<sub>** not *strictly* true.</sub>

Comment: Quoting your statement: "A Contact could contain just one RawContact"...I think a contact is a conjunction of many RawContacts. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: (It's been a while but) I think a `Contact` can contain only single `RawContact` and still be valid.

Comment: Yes, but it will still be valid if it contains many RawContacts.
Thanks for the project though.

Comment: Hey Graeme..i know its not meant to be asked here..what to do to modify/add SipAddress instead of Email Address?

Comment: @Graeme, in your project while updating, getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops); throws me null pointer exception. Can you help me?