# Android how to add phone number to existing contact

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

In my app I have textView where the user can insert phone number and I want to open the native address  and add this number to existing contact,

How can I implement this ?

I manage to open **new contact** with this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, phoneNumber);
```

but my requirement is to also support to add this number for existing contact

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788053/modifying-contact-information