# How to add new field to a contact in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-contacts, contactscontract

I want to add new email address to an exist contact.

I use this code:

```
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> insertEmailList =
            new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    Uri uri=null;
    for (ContactEmail contactEmail : emails) {
        values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, id);
        values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, contactEmail.getEmailAddress());
        values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_CUSTOM);
        uri=contentResolver.insert(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
```

When run this code `uri` is `content://com.android.contacts/data/2135` but my contact is not updated.my app run without exception.

Comment: take a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8802659/726954

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying contact information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788053/modifying-contact-information)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> [image]

<sup>[Image](https://androidexample.com/upload/content/Content_provider_get_email_workflow.png) from [Get Contact Emails By Content Provider - Android Example](https://androidexample.com/get-contact-emails-content-provider)</sup>

```
        Cursor mRawContactCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] {ID},
            null);
    mRawContactCursor.moveToFirst();
    String rawId = mRawContactCursor.getString(mRawContactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID));
```

use this code to find _ID or RAW_CONTACT_ID then update or insert to contact.

```
        for (ContactEmail contactEmail : emails) {
        values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawId);
        values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, "a@a.com");
        values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, type.home);
        contentResolver.insert(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
```